# What conditions on $p$ and $q$ to for which the operator $T_g: L^p([0,1]) \to L^q([0,1])$ is bounded, where $T_g(f)=gf$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

If $1 \leq r < \infty$, and $g$ belongs to $L_r ([0,1])$. We need to determine values of $p$ and $q$ where $1 \leq p,q < \infty$, the operator $T_g: L^p([0,1]) \to L^q([0,1])$ is bounded, where $T_g(f)=gf$  ??

Thank you!

Comment: Are you aware of Holder's inequality?

Comment: I am not sure if it can help me, because left side is 1-norm, right?

Comment: I mean left hand of the Holder inequality?